# Split массива на две части

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Как можно разбить массив на две части в нужном месте, если элемент нужного индекса повторяется. Например, мне нужно получить последнее число в выражении 45-23*996-25 (как разбить массив на месте второго минуса)? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте [split](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods#%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-split) для разбиения и [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) для взятия последнего элемента.

`split` - позволяет превратить строку в массив, разбив ее по разделителю.

`pop` - удаляет последний элемент из массива и возвращает его значение.

```js
var test = '45-23*996-25';
var last =  test.split('-').pop();

console.log(last);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если

> нужно получить последнее число

то можно

```js
var test = '45-23*996-25';
var last =  test.substr(test.lastIndexOf('-')+1);

console.log(last)
```